# Add marker with time validity and near real time

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, asp.net-web-api, signalr, leaflet

In my asp.net web api application with angularJS frontend I want to display marker on a map (google maps or leaflet) with time validity in near real time.

What is that meaning?

1. Each user (client) of the app should immediately (near real time) see when
   another user add a marker on the map.
2. Each added marker can have a different time validity. So if the time
   validity is expired, the marker should be removed from the map and
   each user should see that.

There are two options to do that - client side or server side.
On client side there are "timer" available for each marker (e.g. `.setTimeout()`). But if I have hundreds of markers with different time validity, I would need the same number of timer. Would that not need to much ressources on client side? So I thought it would be better to do this on server side? If the time validity is expired of a marker, I want to remove that marker from each client. But that would mean, that I have to send request for each marker. Is there any best practice to do that? Maybe with SignalR or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to have one setInterval for all the markers?, like a timer that fire an event at regular basis for all the markers. I think I should go for a webservice option to solve this, or maybe a combination of both.

Comment: One timer for all marker doesn't work because each marker has a different validity. What do you mean with web service?